# работа с полями ввода

Tags: java, jtextfield

если я создаю поле ввода и задаю в нём текст

```
JTextField text = new JTextField(7);
text.setText("текст");
```

то по умолчанию курсор окажется в начале текста

как сделать что-бы курсор перемещался в конец слова "текст"

Comment: `setCaretPosition();`

Comment: text.setCaretPosition(); если так то ругается

Comment: на то что надо индекс передать?)

Comment: мне не нужен индекс. мне бы в конец строки. я не пойму что в параметр передать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть метод [`setCaretPosition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html), которому необходимо передать смещение, куда надо установить курсор, в Вашем случае это длина текста в поле `text.getText().length()` или `"текст".length()`

```
JTextField text = new JTextField(7);
text.setText("текст");
text.setCaretPosition(text.getText().length());
```

Comment: точно. никак не привыкну что сначала надо получить что-то а уж апосля считать :)